# Non-editble UITextView returns nil for font

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` which sets both `selectable` and `editable` to false:

```
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
var myString:String = "hello kitty!"
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString)

//some styling
myTextView.attributedText = myMutableString
println(myTextView.font) //returns nil
```

Comment: Are you using a custom font?

Comment: This may be correct since a NSMutableAttributedString can have multiple fonts?

Comment: Yes i'm using custom font.